# How to create an orchestration flow in WSO2 to retrieve user information?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I must do an orchestrated flow in WSO2 of the next case:

Get the next information:

1. The complete name with lastname.
2. Interbank number id
3. Available money for withdraw
4. The last movement with the date

Do a query that starts through the ESB and by using the EndPoint gets a flow which is going to get the information described in the 1, 2, 3 and 4 points.

If the user is 18 years of age or less the service must indicate that they can't do the operation and give a "sorry for the inconvenience, but that they can do the query in 1 year when they are 19 years old" message.

I think to do this orchestration flow I must develop the architecture in Integration Studio and then export this project in Enterprise Integrator server, is this certain?

I am very confused and I don't know by where start it, please kick me for start for understand how to should start to implements this work, thanks very full.

Comment: I highly recommend you go through these trainings, so you understand the basics. https://lms.wso2.com/courses/live-training-wso2-enterprise-integrator-portuguese there are English versions as well.